# Bug bounty XSS vulnerability website payload

Tags: security, xss, payload

I recently started to teach myself XSS vulnerability and stumbled this website for practice.

```
https://sudo.co.il/xss/level2.php
```

But after several attempts to enter several payloads

```
Example: <script>alert('XSS')</script>
```

I can't get XSS to work.

Comment: Have you looked at the page source returned when you try this input string? If you had, it would be pretty obvious that the server is sanitizing input by filtering `<` or `>` in each output (respectively) to their respective associated HTML entity values (`&lt;`, `&gt;`).

Answer (score 2):

The value is reflected in the input value attribute. You can escape this by starting with a `"` and then add other attributes. For example: `" onmouseover="alert('XSS')"`.

To require less user interaction you can change the style: `" onmouseover="alert('XSS')" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px"` or there may be better attributes to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape this by starting with a `"`

For example:`"><img/src=x onerror=alert(origin)>`